# Turning off default scaling options (\setkeys{Gin}) temporarily

Tags: graphics, packages

To set the default scaling values for the `\includegraphics` command, one can use `\setkeys{Gin}{(key)=value)}` from the `graphicx` package. For example, say I put down

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=.7\textwidth}
```

This will automatically scale all succeeding `\includegraphics` commands by the above width value. Is there a way to turn off this setting for certain graphics? That is, is there a way to still use `\includegraphics` without having the width set as the above?

I'm aware that

```
\begin{group}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=.7\textwidth}
\includegraphics{pizza.jpg} %this uses setted values
\end{group}
\includegraphics{pizza.jpg} %this uses normal values
```

works, but I'm wondering if I can do this without having to surround the `\setkeys{Gin}` command.

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=2cm]{pizza.jpg}` (or the length you want) should override the default value. *Never* use `\begin{group}` and `\end{group}`.

Comment: What I mean is that I want to `\includegraphics{pizza.jpg}` in its native setting, i.e., with absolutely no scaling values in place. Something like `[width=2cm]` only overwrites the scaling value with another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the value stored in `\Gin@nat@width`, defining a handier interface to it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setkeys{Gin}{width=30pt} % exaggerated for the example
\makeatletter
\let\ginnatwidth\Gin@nat@width
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image-9x16}

\includegraphics[width=\ginnatwidth]{example-image-9x16}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, late response! Yes, this works perfectly. By extension, one can do the same for height as well. :)

Comment: umm, this doesn't actually turn it off, but sets it do a default value. What I mean is that `includegraphics` resizes `width` when only `height` is given. I have a global default `width=\linewidth`, but for a particular figure with many images, I want to have a default height and forget about the default `width`. Using `\Gin@nat@width` doesn't let `includegraphics` to adapt `width` to newer height