# AIAA Latex template and tikzexternalize

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using the AIAA class v3.8 from Texlive 2014 distribution for a communication paper. I try to use the export feature of Tikz, with `tikzexternalize`, as described in [the documentation](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf#section.33).

For me, `tikzexternal` fails to handle the size of exported plots. On the picture below, 1 stands for the correct result, build with:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

and 2 for the incorrect result, build with:

```
\usepackage{tikzexternal}
\tikzexternalize
```

[image]

See, in page 1, the stroke is 1 cm width and height. In page 2, it covers all the text width, which is not requested.

The problem occurs with document class `aiaa-tc`, not with standard class `article` (where all outputs are similar to page 1). What is wrong?

The code used is the following:

```
\documentclass{aiaa-tc}

% leads to result 1
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

%% leads to result 2
%\usepackage{tikzexternal}
%\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1cm,1cm) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{A line}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please read the documentation I gave the link to: "**Using the Library Without pgf or pgfplots Installed** There is a small replacement package tikzexternal.sty
which can be used once every figure has been exported. The idea is to uncomment `\usepackage{tikz}` and `\usepackage{pgfplots}` and write `\usepackage{tikzexternal}` instead"

Comment: @JMP ^^ You have mail.

Comment: Welcome! Have you examined the exported file? Is the size incorrect there? If you specify an absolute dimension rather than a relative one (e.g. `10cm` rather than `.5\textwidth`) does it make a difference? Does this only apply to images drawn with `pgfplots` i.e. not regular `tikzpicture`s?

Comment: Have you read the section of the `pgfplots` manual covering usage of TikZ's externalisation?

Comment: The behavior is the same with an absolute width: if I set `5cm`, I get picture 2. When I open the generated figure PDF file, the width is 41 mm. I cannot say if it is normal I do not get 50 mm. Also, same behavior with simple `tikz` commands, such as `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);`.

Comment: I have just tried the "manual" externalization, and the behavior is the same: it works with `article` document class (picture 1), not with `aiaa-tc` class (picture 2).

Comment: OK. In that case, I'd recommend editing your question to include the simplest possible case (i.e. the `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);` with no `pgfplots`) and to make clear that it is the `aiaa-tc` class which is part of the problem i.e. that it works with `article`. All of that information helps to narrow the problem down.

Comment: I'm suspicious of this line in the class: `\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}` but I can't quite see how exactly it is resulting in the effect you're seeing.

Comment: OK. I see. I was confusing the correct and incorrect. So the line above is telling `graphicx` to scale the images to make them as large as possible, keeping the aspect ratio and given the size of the text area. It may be that this line is there because that is how AIAA want images to be included. If so, the 'incorrect' result is actually something like the one you want, though it might be better not to scale the image down in the first place. Otherwise, you need to change the inclusion command used for externalised images to override those keys.

Comment: Great! I cannot say if this is what AIAA really wants, because it makes the use of sub-figures virtually impossible. So, how do I change the inclusion command? And what do you mean with "better not to scale the image down"?

Comment: I'm not sure. Normally `/pgf/images/include external` but I'm not sure that will work here. (See page 616 of the current manual.) Maybe it would be easier to just reset the keys to override those defaults e.g. `\setkeys{Gin}{width=.5\linewidth]`, for example. Put it in a group if you want to limit the effect to particular images. Re. the scaling: I just meant that if you are going to end up with full-width images, it would be better not to generate them at half width and then let them be scaled back up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the class includes this line

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
```

which tells `graphicx` to apply these settings every time `\includegraphics` or similar is used. When you load the externalisation library normally, TikZ uses `\pgfimage` to include externalised images. When you use `tikzexternal` instead, it uses `\includegraphics`

```
\def\pgfincludeexternalgraphics#1{%
        \begingroup
        \pgfexternalreaddpth{#1}%
        \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics{#1}}%
        \ifdim\pgfretval=0pt
                \box1
        \else
                \dimen0=\pgfretval\relax
                \hbox{\lower\dimen0 \box1 }%
        \fi
        \endgroup
}
```

So the class's keys affect the settings relevant to image inclusion only when loading `tikzexternal` and not when using the externalisation library with the default inclusion command.

If you are sure that it is permissible in terms of submission guidelines, you can override the keys set for image inclusion by the class either globally or for particular images.

For example:

```
\documentclass{aiaa-tc}

% leads to result 1
% \usepackage{tikz}
% \usetikzlibrary{external}
% \tikzexternalize

%% leads to result 2
\usepackage{tikzexternal}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=.25\linewidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1cm,1cm) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{A line}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: smaller version]

Comment: There is still a difference with `tickzpictures` containing a PGF plot from package `pgfplots` (wich was the starter of the question). You can solve this by resetting the `Gin` key to its initial value: [Turning off default scaling options (\setkeys{Gin}) temporarily](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102714/turning-off-default-scaling-options-setkeysgin-temporarily), it consists to add in the preamble `\makeatletter
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\Gin@nat@width}
\makeatother`

Comment: That's probably true. You're approximating the correct width to use, really. Certainly obliterating the class settings will work. Whether this leaves your document in a submissible state is another matter.