# includegraphics scale not working

Tags: graphics, pdftex, sweave, size

Im trying to change the size of the picture with "scale" but is not working

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=1cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}


\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{D:/R/pdf/pruebas/caratula3.jpg}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{D:/R/pdf/pruebas/caratula3.jpg}
\end{center}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

This is the image.

[image: This is the image]

Thanks!

Comment: A side note: Do not use the `{center}` environment in cases like this since it add additional vertical spacing. Better use `\centering` at the begin of the `{figure}` environment. Then everything inside will be centers too, but without (unwanted) extra spacing.

Comment: I only see one image, whereas your code should produce two.

Comment: Mmm... tex distribution?  i think that sweave. And I compile with the option "compile PDF" in RStudio

Comment: Sweave is an R programme that can take a mixture of latex and R, execute the R code and insert the result into a resulting latex file which is then compiled by latex. R and Latex gas nothing in common, you cannot compile a latex file without having installed a latex installation (in the same manner as Rstudio cannot compile R code without an R installation). Do we need to know which latex installation (and version you are using). Perhaps look at the top of the latex log file?

Comment: Sorry, I´, noob in this program. Can my version be  "MiKTex 2.9"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean it isn't working?  What happens if you add an image with scale=1?  Also, don't load `graphics`.

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=1cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{center}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}
\end{center}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer.
with isnt working i mean "scale" does not modify the size of the image. 
And when i add an image with scale=1, both imagen remains the same

Comment: I don't understand your comment, sorry.

Comment: @MicaelSalomon remember to do as JPi did, load the same image with `scale=0.5` and `scale=1` in the same document. Otherwise, if the image is very large, might not see a difference. If it still does not work, then please let us see the image.

Comment: Ok, @daleif. I already try that and it doesnt work. Now im gonna put the image on the post. I hope you can help me

Comment: Also, I'm not sure it's a good idea to set negative margins in geometry, as you did.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem (images not scaling with `\includegraphics[scale=value]{image}`).

In my case, I was unintentionally setting the default scaling values for the `\includegraphics` command, as detailed here: [Turning off default scaling options (\setkeys{Gin}) temporarily](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102714/turning-off-default-scaling-options-setkeysgin-temporarily)

In my case, fixing the problem was as easy as removing the following line:

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=<value>}
```

I hope others find this answer useful!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was working in the following environment for some reason:

```
\begin{figure*}
\end{figure*}
```

When I removed the *, the scale function worked fine again.

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{image file goes here}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are PDFs that cannot be scaled for some reason. As a workaround, you can use `resizebox`:

```latex
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\includegraphics{Jupyter_logo.pdf}}
```

---

If you are interested in such an example, you can download the SVG file of the Jupyter logo from [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jupyter_logo.svg) and convert it using `rsvg-convert -f pdf -o Jupyter_logo.pdf Jupyter_logo.svg`. In my case it does not change the size, if I specify the `width` option of `includegraphics` and is not visible if I set something like `scale=2`. YMMV.